# Rails: one app with 2 domains - share authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

My site is at mydomain.com on Heroku with Devise authentication.

I bought a short url me.do that I also point to my same Heroku app.

When a user is signed in on mydomain.com I also need them to be signed in on me.do so when they go to me.do after signing in at mydomain.com they don't have to sign in again.

How can I share authentication sessions using Devise on both mydomain.com and me.do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to share authentication across domains, since the authentication usually is bound to cookies (sessions) which only bind to one domain and are not accessible across domains.

The only way you can manage to have something like this is to make sure you set cookies on both domains on login. You can do this via a redirect loop:

- login request arrives at domain1 (from login form for example)
- you set the session cookie for domain1
- then make a redirect to domain2 and set a session cookie there
- and then redirect the user back to domain1 (proceeding where he originally was going)

to make sure this is not an endless loop you have to add some parameters in the redirects to know how to handle the situation.

BUT if at all possible to avoid it, i would advise you not to implement this. It is really bad practice to have not unique domains. even allowing domains with www and without can lead to quite a bit of confusion for the user and a lot of headaches to the developer - in your case it will be even worse.

The sessions are not as useful as they would normally be. Setting additional cookies or session values does NOT work anymore (unless you do the loop every time again). And until the user actually uses the second domain his session there might even have expired (depending how your authentication framework handles it).
Those are just some of the issues you might run into.

Comment: thanks for the great response @maxigs , sounds like this would not be a good idea to do. I think instead we'll just redirect the user to our main domain site and maybe use history.js to change the url in the browser back to the short url once they get there. thanks!