# Devise multiple domains authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have 2 domains on one app - example1.com and example2.com. It is necessary to log in at all, when authorization in any of them via rails4 devise gem.
How is it implemented?

Answer (score 0):

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777341/rails-one-app-with-2-domains-share-authentication). You must redirect your login request in domain1.dn, after if login success, redirect to domain2.dn and set cookies !